# Windbg and Dump File to trace application errors

Tags: windbg

Recently i installed an application that was built using Delphi , when i try to load some files in the application i get Access violation at address 00000000 . i couldn't find any info about the problem in the event viewer so i went to use process explorer to generate a dumb file for the process and then used the file in WinDbg and the output was as follow:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25200.1003 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\xVisualizer3D.dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Sat Nov 12 18:56:37.000 2022 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:32.000
................................................................
..................................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Visualizer3D.exe
eax=00320620 ebx=0008e301 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=767939c0 esp=0018fed4 ebp=0018ff04 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
user32!NtUserWaitMessage+0x15:
767939c0 83c404          add     esp,4
0:000> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: kernel32!gpServerNlsUserInfo                  ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 1343

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
    Value: Create

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 289371

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 6

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 0

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 7

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 562

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 407939

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 69

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 32

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 3.0.0.30


FILE_IN_CAB:  xVisualizer3D.dmp

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000e60

PROCESS_NAME:  Visualizer3D.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

STACK_TEXT:  
0018fed4 006b0756     0018ff30 006b0773 0018ff04 user32!NtUserWaitMessage+0x15
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0018ff04 006af968     001a036e 00000113 00000001 Visualizer3D!TMethodImplementationIntercept+0x1c3ece
0018ff58 00bbca0a     00bbcab9 0018ff78 00bbcad1 Visualizer3D!TMethodImplementationIntercept+0x1c30e0
0018ff88 7628343d     7efde000 0018ffd4 771f9832 Visualizer3D!TMethodImplementationIntercept+0x6d0182
0018ff94 771f9832     7efde000 77ecc335 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0018ffd4 771f9805     00bbc8a8 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0018ffec 00000000     00bbc8a8 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  visualizer3d+1c3ece

MODULE_NAME: Visualizer3D

IMAGE_NAME:  Visualizer3D.exe

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_Visualizer3D.exe!Unknown

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 7

IMAGE_VERSION:  3.0.0.30

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {860298c4-6043-6454-52eb-067e0c079603}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

I don't know what to do after this point , and looked through the info above and couldn't find any useful information about the cause of the problem and not sure ,but i think i'm having problem with symbols also in the debugger .

So what can i do now to find the cause of the exception ?

Note: I don't have the source code for this program , also i tried to install the application on another pc (with win 10 installed) and worked without any problem .

Regards

Comment: How have you generated the dmp file? It doesn't show an Access violation error.

Comment: @harrymc using Process Explorer , created a dmp file while the process is running and throwing the exception , Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: The dump shows what the process was doing when dumped, which is just running. See [Creating an Application Crash Dump](https://helgeklein.com/blog/creating-an-application-crash-dump/). You could upload the crash file if you wish us to have a look at it.

Comment: I followed all the instructions in the site , but no crash dump was generated , is there another method ?

Comment: What is your Windows version?

Comment: @harrymc windows 7

Comment: This advice for getting dumps should have worked on Windows 7. The application might be trapping its crashes, for some reason, this way suppressing the dumps. What is this app? If this is OKM Visualizer 3D Studio, there might exist newer versions, and their Support may answer.

Comment: yes , it is OKM Visualizer 3D Studio , there is no new version available and the support team taking forever to reply sir . If there is a way to catch this exception in any debugger please let me know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Windows mechanism for
[Creating an Application Crash Dump](https://helgeklein.com/blog/creating-an-application-crash-dump/)
by setting the registry key of
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\SomeProcess.exe`,
does not work for the OKM Visualizer 3D Studio application,
you need to debug it yourself.

You need to run the application *from the debugger*.
You could try Windbg or Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code.

This way, the debugger will be in control all along.
You need to assure that the debugger is set to trap the error code of
Access violation.

This will require some knowledge of reading the execution stack
and its parameters.

However, as you do not have the source for the application, and as
the Support of the app does not answer, it's unclear what you will
achieve by better understanding the problem.
You might be better off trying to find an alternative product.

I would also try this product on a computer running Window 10.
Many products today no longer support Windows 7, and this product
might be one of them.